# Schwarz's Lemma, $F(z):=\frac{f(z)}{z}$ is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis

Schwarz's Lemma says: If $f$ is analytic in the unit disk $U:|z|<1$ and
$$
f(0) = 0\ and\ |f(z)| \leq 1\ \forall\ z\ in\ U
$$
then $|f(z)|\leq|z|$ for all $z$ in $U$.

In my textbook, the proof of it involves the definition of $F(z)$: $F(z):=\frac{f(z)}{z}$ for $z\neq0$, and $F(0)=f'(0)$. It then says $F(z)$ is analytic in $U$. I wonder why $F(z)$ is analytic at $z=0$.

Comment: It helps if you write $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$. If $f(0) = 0$ then you know $a_0 = 0$ and $f'(0) = a_1$ so you can argue $F(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n+1}z^{n}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(z)= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k z^{k} $ for $|z| <1$ then $a_0=0,f'(0)=a_1$ and $F(z)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k z^{k-1} $. This series is also convergent for $|z|<1$ so its sum is analytic.